# Finding the partial derivatives of $f(x,y,z)= \int_{0}^{x}t^tdt + x ^{\sin(y^z)}$ and the first derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y,z)= \int_{0}^{x}t^tdt + x ^{\sin(y^z)}$$

The derivative would be $f'(x,y,z)(h^1,h^2,h^3)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h^1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}h^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}h^3.$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=...?$ Could someone put in a step by step on there?
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^{\sin(y^z)}\ln( \sin (y^z))\cos (y^z)zy^{z-1}$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=x^{\sin(y^z)}\ln( \sin (y^z))\cos (y^z)y^z \ln z  ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $t\mapsto t^t$ is smooth, the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\mapsto\int_0^xt^t\mathrm{d}t\right)(x)=x^x.$$

Next, recall that
$$y^z=\mathrm{e}^{z\ln y},\quad x^{\sin\left(y^z\right)}=\mathrm{e}^{\sin\left(y^z\right)\ln x}$$
so that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\mapsto y^z\right)(y)=\mathrm{e}^{z\ln y}\frac{z}{y}=zy^{z-1}$$
and then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\mapsto x^{\sin\left(y^z\right)}\right)(y)=\mathrm{e}^{\sin\left(y^z\right)\ln x}\cos\left(y^z\right)zy^{z-1}\ln x=x^{\sin\left(y^z\right)}\cos\left(y^z\right)zy^{z-1}\ln x.$$

Finally, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(y\mapsto x^{\sin\left(y^z\right)}\right)(z)=x^{\sin\left(y^z\right)}\cos\left(y^z\right)\ln y\ln x.$$

Comment: Is this correct, my lack of understanding lays at the fundamental thereom: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\mapsto\int_1^xt^t\mathrm{d}t\right)(x)=x^x-1?$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\mapsto\int_x^{x+3}t^t\mathrm{d}t\right)(x)={(x+3)}^{x+3} -x^x ?$

Comment: No, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\mapsto\int_c^x t^t\mathrm{d}t\right)(x)=x^x$ for any constant $c$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\mapsto\int_x^{x+3} t^t\mathrm{d}t\right)(x)=\left(x+3\right)^{x+3}-x^x$ is correct.